# Загрузка файла на сервер в Python с помощью requests.post

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Возникла необходимость в отправке файлов на сервер средствами Python, код написанный по документации выдает 500 код ошибки.

```
import requests
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post/files'
file = {'schema.json': open('schema.json', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=file)
print(response.text)
```

При этом Curl запрос с тем же содержимым `curl -X POST "https://httpbin.org/post/files" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "payload=@schema.json;type=application/json"` возвращает 200 код. Как в Python добиться такого же результата?

---

В этом варианте работает

```
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post/files'
files = {'payload': ('README.md', open('./data/README.md', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Но появилась другая проблема, как отдельный файл работает, а добавляешь его в программу и опять выдает 500 код. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Попробуйте указать словарь с заголовками (параметр `headers`).

Comment: response = requests.post(url, files=file, headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} ) - не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Если убрать /files -- работает